# How to write Selenium Script for Naukri jobs search functionality

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

Writing selenium script for search functionality. Search functionality works as mentioned below.
User could search for any keyword say "Java developer jobs". Results will display even if one word from the keyword is available. 
If the word "java" is available in a particular job then that particular job will lists in the result.

Searched using keyword **'Experienced Java Developer'** and the results are as follows:

```
Total results: 6
Senior Developer
Java Developer
Experienced Java Programmer
Experienced Java Developer
Java Programmer
Experienced Testers
Software Developer
```

In the above results, some of the results have just one word from the keyword. 
How should I write a script to cover this.

I tried as mentioned below:

1. Search using `keyword`;
2. Split the `keyword` (here in this case we get three words such as `Experienced`, `Java` and `Developer`);
3. Use enhanced for loop (search each word is available in the result, or not);
4. If it's not available, display the result;
5. Using `arraylist` & capturing all the results from the loop.

It looks like it's working well, but I'm getting multiple duplicate values.

How can I handle this situation?

**Example:** Naukri.com

Comment: Can you share your efforts ? Whatever code you have written to achieve what you have achieved.

Comment: @Divya Can you consider sharing your work with us? Thanks

Comment: I couldnt share the code Abhinav. I can give you some more data..
based on nested for loop.. first word from the keyword "java developer" goes through the loop and verify the results list and displays the results which has no keyword and again goes through the loop with the second word from the keyword.. and displays the results.. I am confused with how to compare both the results.. I used ArrayList too...any suggestions pls

Comment: You can store the data in a Set if the duplicates are bothering you, in that case you have to get the visible text of the links and and store it in a Set and use them accordingly. Though to understand the problem better need to look into the code, if you can't share the code maybe you can share the some similar code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily handle the duplicate values. try this way...

1. Split the key string. Like "Experienced Java Developer" to "Experienced" "Java" "Developer"
2. Put them in a list(*keyList*) from where you can compare.
3. Now take the current element(in this case the first element) from the search list.
4. Split it and put them on another list(*isFoundList*).
5. Start searching on each of *isFoundList* with all elements from *keyList*
6. - If any match found print them or save them to some where and take the next element from the search list.
   - Else take the next element from the search list.
7. Repeat from **step 3** until the search list is finished.